# passing struts2 perameter to different webpage

Tags: java, web, struts2, tags

I have a struts2 action class that executes when the user presses a link

```
public class goToUserProfile {
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("An action class has been called!");
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

this is the tag

```
<s:a action="goToUserProfile">
```

In order to show profile specific information I need to pass the user ID using struts

```
/profile.action?userNo=846258
```

The thing is. I don't really know how to pass a value through an action class
Assume I have all the user IDs in an array (for now) how would I pass one of those IDs onto the profile page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, in this example,

1)create a private Long variable called userNo

I chose Long because your userNo looks like it will be a "big" integer

2) Create a getter and setter for userNo

```
public class goToUserProfile {
    private Long userNo;
    public Long getUserNo(){
        return this.userNo
    }
    public void setUserNo(String rhs){
        this.userNo;
    }
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("An action class has been called!");
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

When you link to `/profile.action?userNo=846258`
The setter method will be called on the action setting `userNo`.
When the action forwards to profile.jsp, ?or whatever you called it, you can access userNo with something like

```
<s:property value="userNo"/>
```

Additionally, if you dont want to create a field in your action class you can just call your action as you are `/profile.action?userNo=846258`
and in your jsp access it like this

```
<s:property value="%{#parameters['userNo']}"/>
```

This way accesses the request parameters itself.

Hope that helps